# How to iterate into most recent path given a list of both paths and .txt files?

Tags: python, automation, ui-automation, pathlib, file-management

I have an interesting problem that has kind of been scratching my brain. I am returning a list of both Windows Paths and .txt files. I would like my program to first check if the most recent file (sorted by mtime) is a dir, and if not then to iterate through the list until finding the most recent dir.

I know this has to be done with a for loop, but I just can't seem to figure it out.

Any help please? Thanks

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

#change to parent dir of photos / replace with mirror path
event_dir = r"G:\Event Photos"
#sorts all paths in folder by date
paths = sorted(Path(event_dir).iterdir(), key = os.path.getmtime)
print(paths)
#changes dir to most recent folder
`if paths[-1].is_dir():
    os.chdir(paths[-1])
    print("Changed into most recent DIR")
else:
    print("Error - Lastest file is not a dir")

print(os.getcwd())`
```

I was going to change the else statement into something along the lines of:

```
if paths[-1].is_dir():
    os.chdir(paths[-1])
    print("Changed into most recent DIR")
else:
    for path in paths:
        path.is_dir()
        if path.is_dir():
            os.chdir(path)
            break
print(os.getcwd())
```

Comment: So, you just want to find the last created directory and file. If file is newer then do nothing, when directory is newer then do what?

Comment: @Xenobiologist So I have a directory containing both files and folders, I would like to first check if the latest item in the directory list is a folder - if not continue until finding the latest item in the list that is a folder/directory. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you out?

```
import os, glob
directory = r"c:\Autoit"
latest_file_or_dir = max(glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '*')), key=os.path.getmtime)
latest_dir = max(glob.glob(os.path.join(directory, '*/')), key=os.path.getmtime)

if os.path.isfile(latest_file_or_dir):
    print('Latest modified is a file: ' + latest_file_or_dir)
    print('Latest directory is: ' + latest_dir)
else:
    print('Latest changed item is a directory: ' + latest_dir)
```